# windows phone 8.1 REST WCF Service Upload image

Tags: wcf, rest, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, httprequest

I want to upload image to my wcf service from windows phone 8.1 app. I use HttpRequest/HttpResponse Messages

**Client code:**

```
private async void RecognizeProduct()
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();


        byte[] arr = originalBitmap.ToByteArray();
        var barcodeImageForm = new ByteArrayContent(arr, 0, arr.Count());
        barcodeImageForm.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/bmp");

        form.Add(barcodeImageForm, "image", "barcodeImage.bmp");

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:51746/Service.svc/recognize", form);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        httpClient.Dispose();
        string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
```

**Service interface:**

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/recognize", Method="POST")]
    string RecognizeBarcode(Stream barcodeImageStream);
```

**Service method:**

```
 public string RecognizeBarcode(Stream barcodeImageStream)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        barcodeImageStream.CopyTo(ms);
        Bitmap barcodePhoto = new Bitmap(barcodeImageStream);
        string barcodeResult = BarcodeEncoder.BarcodeEncode(barcodePhoto);
        barcodeImageStream.Close();
        ms.Close();
        return barcodeResult;
    }
```

**Web.config**

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             transferMode="Streamed"  openTimeout="00:25:00" closeTimeout="00:25:00"
             sendTimeout="00:25:00" receiveTimeout="00:25:00">
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" name="WhereCheaperService.Service">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"  behaviorConfiguration="web" contract="WhereCheaperService.IService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="max" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <!--BEGIN ADD ENDPOINT BEHAVIOR-->
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name ="web">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <!--END of ADD ENDPOINT BEHAVIOR-->
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Client are founding the service successfully but the request don't work. I get error:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll but was not handled in user code
```

How i can solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MSDN writes on the Bitmap Constructor(Stream)'s page (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you get a 'System.ArgumentException' if:

> stream does not contain image data or is null.
>   -or-
>   stream contains a PNG image file with a single dimension greater than 65,535 pixels.

you should check these conditions!